# How to get the home page item button conditionally styled in react?

Tags: reactjs, menu, material-ui, react-router-dom

I am using react and Material UI to render a navbar and trying to conditionally give a style to the selected menu item according to the url.
I am using useLocation to get the current url:

```
import { Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
const location = useLocation();
const menuItem = ['Pool', 'Mining', 'Leveraged', 'Lock-up', 'Docs', 'Profile'];
```

Then I conditionally redirect to the url and if the url is pool then I want it to redirect to the home page ('/').

```
{menuItem.map((item) => (
<MenuItem
  classes={{
    selected: classes.selected,
  }}
  component={Link}
  to={item === 'Pool' ? '/' : `${item}`}
  key={item}
  selected={location.pathname === `/${item}`}
>
  {item}
</MenuItem>
))}
```

The problem is that while the selected style work for all the pathnames, it doesn't work with the homepage which is pool.

This is the result I get and want (the border-bottom white) when an item is selected according to the url

[image]

While the only menu item that doesn't get styled is the home page
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
   selected={item === 'Pool' ? location.pathname === '/' : location.pathname === `/${item}`}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a specific solution to your immediate problem, you need to modify the condition in `selected=` to include the case that you want, something like `|| (item === 'Pool' && location.pathname === '/')` or similar. You may have to fiddle with it.

As a broader answer, consider using react-router's built-in [NavLink](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink) component. They already have an [isActive](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink/isactive-func) prop specifically for dealing with complex cases like this. No sense reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Yes, I used the NavLink but the problem was the same so I decided to go on with the MUI official docs where they use  the component={Link} with react-router.